# Javascript Reference 404 after Clearing Cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, caching

UI newbie here.  A project is using nvd3, and to test a chart/javascript, the cache had to be cleared.  Now, one of the script references to the nvd3 chart libraries is registering a 404 error and the graph is displaying null even though source code shows the proper data.  Navigating the links via the source code seems to work.  There's also a "Browser Link: Failed to send message to browser link server:
Error: SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call .start() before .send()" error now, but I changed the Chrome settings to use a proxy server for LAN and bypass proxy server for local address, which fixed this error when it popped up earlier.  I looked into rewriting, but I don't think that's happening, and I don't see any reason why it would now and not before.  Also, I tried loading the libraries one after the other, like below, in case some dependency was locking up, but that also generated a 404 error on the closing script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getScript("/Content/lib/d3/d3.min.js",
        function() {
            $.getScript("/Content/lib/novus-nvd3/nv.d3.min.js");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Does anyone have an idea as to why this worked before cache clearing, and how does one fix it?  Below is the script section (jQuery was referenced in the header):

```
@section Scripts{
    <!-- page specific plugins -->
    <!-- nvd3 charts -->
    <script src="/Content/lib/d3/d3.min.js"></script> //404 NOW!
    <script src="/Content/lib/novus-nvd3/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- flot charts-->
    <script src="/Content/lib/flot/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/lib/flot/jquery.flot.pie.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/lib/flot/jquery.flot.resize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/lib/flot/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js"></script>
    <!-- clndr -->
    <script src="/Content/lib/underscore-js/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/lib/CLNDR/src/clndr.js"></script>
    <!-- easy pie chart -->
    <script src="/Content/lib/easy-pie-chart/dist/jquery.easypiechart.min.js"></script>
    <!-- owl carousel -->
    <script src="/Content/lib/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

    <!-- dashboard functions -->
    <script src="/Content/js/apps/tisa_dashboard.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function cumulativeTestData() {
            var closes = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Coordinates))')
            return [
                {
                    key: "Prices",
                    //mean: 60,
                    values: closes //Chart data is correct in source
                },
            ];
        }
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error disappeared when I removed a duplicate reference to JQuery on the preceding page that directed to the page in question.